# The URL of the product and category with the same base prefix in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a code that in Woocommerce changes the base in the category url to the base of the store url. That is, if we have the url base of the products store, then we need to set up a Database of product categories in the Permalinks settings, too, products, and for permanent product links, select this `/products/%product_cat`%/. Then we insert the following code into `functions.ph`p and everything works.

```
/**
 * Set product category base url same as a shop base
 *
 * @param array $rules
 *
 * @see https://gist.github.com/levantoan/fc705c5ae4739e6d87e2ec51b257ea5c
 * @return array
 */
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array',
    function( $rules ) {
        $new_rules = array();
        global $sitepress;
        if ( $sitepress ) {
            // Disable wpml filters to get all the product terms.
            remove_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ) );
            remove_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ) );
            remove_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ) );
            // Get the terms.
            $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'post_type' => 'product', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        } else {
            $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'post_type' => 'product', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
        }
        // Check if any terms are present and the there are no errors.
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                // Detect term language.
                $language_code = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_language_code', null, array( 'element_id' => (int) $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'element_type' => 'product_cat' ) );

                // Check the language code.
                if ( $language_code === 'en' ) {
                    $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/en/' ) );
                } else {
                    $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
                }
                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                $baseterm = str_replace( $siteurl, '', get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) );

                // Rules for a specific category.
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug;
                // Rules for a category pagination.
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&paged=$matches[1]';
                $new_rules[ $baseterm . '(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&feed=$matches[1]';
            }
        }
        if ( $sitepress ) {
            add_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ), 10, 4 );
            add_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ), 1, 1 );
            add_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ), 10, 2 );
        }
        return $new_rules + $rules;
    }
);

/**
 * Flush rewrite rules when create new term
 * need for a new product category rewrite rules
 *
 */
function imp_create_term() {
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'imp_create_term' );
```

The code works fine. But I need to change the url structure for the product, excluding the category in it. That is, now the url of the product looks like this - `site.com/products/category-name/product-name` , and you need it to be `site.com/products/product-name` . It is clear that you need to change the permanent link to the product in the Permanent Link settings, but then a 404 error appears in place of the product page. Can you tell me how to change this code so that everything works fine???